# How to Update Plotly Plot on form submition with ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django-forms, django-views, ajaxform

I'm building an app in Django. I have a slider which sends an angle value to the Django views and plolty plot is rendered on the page. I didn't wanted the page to be refreshed whenever slider is changed so I used AJAX. But now here is the issue. As page doesn't refresh so plot is not updated for the value selected on slider. Here is my HTML

```
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<div class="x">
<head>

    <title>Forbes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'home.css' %}">

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Intensity Plot</h1>

    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>

    <form method="post" id="intensity_plots"> {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="am0SNvhTILZN9hqtsDEOiGZhiMYZXiWBRpzhVQbnDKhT89mjz8YOfqmXuLhTM5Uh">

        <div id="div_id_slider" class="control-group">
            <label for="id_slider" class="control-label requiredField">Select angle range
                <span class="asteriskField">*</span>
            </label>

            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="slider" class="rangeslider" required="" id="id_slider" readonly="readonly" style="left: 0%; width: 15%;">
                <p></p>
                <div class="demo">
                    <div type="submit" id="slider-vertical"></div>
                </div>

                <script>
                    $('#id_slider').attr("readonly", true)
                    $( "#slider-vertical" ).slider({
                    orientation: "vertical",
                        range: "min",
                        min: 0,
                        max: 360,
                        value: 0,
                        slide: function( event, ui ) {
                            $( "#id_slider" ).val(ui.value);
                        },
                        stop: function(event, ui) {
                            $('#intensity_plots').submit();
                        },
                        });

                    $( "#id_slider" ).val($( "#slider-vertical" ).slider( "values", 0 ));
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>

        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>

    </form>
</div>

<div class="x">&nbsp;</div>

<div id="refresh" class="x">
        {% autoescape off %}
        {{ plot_div }}
        {% endautoescape %}
</div>

<style>
    div.x {
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on('submit','#intensity_plots',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'forbes',
                data:{
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
                },

            success: function (resp) {
                console.log("Data Retrieved");
                $('div#refresh').append(resp.data);

                },
            });

    })

 </script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on('submit','#intensity_plots',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'forbes',
                data:{
                    angle:$("#id_slider").val(),
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
                },

            success: function () {
                console.log("Form Submitted");

                },
            });

    })

 </script>

</html>
```

I used POST method to send slider(angle) value to my views.py file. Then I created another AJAX call using GET method to update the plot but it isn't working. My django views file is here

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from plotly.offline import plot
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import math as m
import numpy as np


def forbes(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        y = []
        if request.POST.get('angle') == '360' or '0':
            angle = request.POST.get('angle')
            if not angle:
                print('No value selected')
                y.append(0)
            else:
                x = int(angle)
                print('value of angle =', x)
                y.append(x)
            print(y[0])
        x = y[0]
        X = np.linspace(0, x, x + 1)
        print(X)
        Y = (2 + 2 * np.sin(2 * X * m.pi / 180) + 2 * pow(np.sin(X * m.pi / 180), 2)) / (4 * m.sqrt(2))
        trace1 = go.Scatter(x=X, y=Y, marker={'color': 'red', 'symbol': 104, 'size': 10},
                            mode="lines", name='Unit Intensity Curve')
        data = go.Data([trace1])
        layout = go.Layout(title="Polarizer Angle vs Unit Intensity",
                           xaxis={'title': 'Polarizer Angle (Degrees)'},
                           yaxis={'title': 'Unit Intensity (W/m^2)'},
                           width=900)
        figure = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
        plot_div = plot(figure, auto_open=True, output_type='div')
        return render(request, 'forbes.html', context={'plot_div': plot_div})

    return render(request, 'forbes.html')
```

here is my urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('forbes', views.forbes)
    ]
```

So how can i use AJAX to update the plotly plot without page refresh whenever slider value is changed?

Answer (score 1):

in your views.py file
`return render(request, 'forbes.html', context={'plot_div': plot_div})`

instead of returning the whole template again you just have to return data as Response in JSON format i.e `return JsonResponse(data)` and use those values to update the view accordingly using Jquery.

```
success: function (response) {
    console.log("Form Submitted");
    // do something with data in response
    },
});
```